# Problem installing ubuntu TOSHIBA Satellite P855-32U

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a new laptop which runs win 8 (UEFI firmware), I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.2 but I cannot even make the liveUSB start booting.

I have test the USB in another laptop and I know it was created without problems.
If I switch the Boot Mode in BIOS from UEFI to CSM, it doesn't recognize the USB or the HDD.

While booting if I press <kbd>F12</kbd> sometimes it recognizes the USB sometimes not, but even when it does, if I select it the laptop boots to Windows and just ignores the USB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system). Please remember, you must install both OS in same mode (UEFI or Legacy). You can't run both in different mode unless you change the options each time you boot. Also use USB 2.0 ports if available.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had seen some similar articles, but i tried the instructions again. I managed to go into the ubuntu setup but when i started the installation, no other software was found (win 8, because of the CSM option), on the other hand if i use UEFI it still doesnt start. so i am still not able to dual boot my system... my question is if i install ubuntu on CSM, I will have to change between the boot modes, but i will have access to all partitions with linux? right?

Comment: try with 64bit. 32bit option doesn't detect UEFI. Also disable secure boot or use 12.10 64 bit

Comment: I am using 12.10 64bit, still with UEFI on and secure boot off, no usb is recognized, something strange, during some of my tries the usb was actualy listed under the lan or the cd drive, could it be some hardware failure?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide additional information only by editing your question and not within a comment. Comments might/will eventually be deleted and so your information would get lost.

Comment: Try downloading another EFI-bootable USB flash drive or CD-R image, such as the one for rEFInd (http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). At the very least, that will give you information on whether you can boot something else in EFI mode; if so, you can concentrate on fixing the Ubuntu medium and if not, you can concentrate on finding firmware options to boot. rEFInd in particular can redirect the boot process, so if you plug in two USB flash drives, you might get the Ubuntu installer to boot via rEFInd.

Comment: Also check that your machine has the latest firmware. Toshibas had some problems with getting the signing keys into the correct databases, resulting in not being able to secure boot Ubuntu 12.04.2 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

turn off secure boot and change setup order to run cd/dvd first and burn ubuntu to dvd and reboot and should start up from cd.

Comment: Please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I just got my hands on a Toshiba satellite p855-33C and had a similar problem. After entering the BIOS to disable "secure" boot and switching to CSM mode from "advanced" tab, I was able to boot Ubuntu 12.04 64bit from a bootable usb stick created as per ubuntu instructions. I then inserted the stick on a usb 3.0 slot and powered-up.

I chose "Try without install" and the system came-up in 73 sec. Pretty decent for a live usb system. The start-up script even detected that I was using a Greek keyboard added the Greek layout to the list of available layouts and offered to change the default folder names (even though I selected English at start-up for system language - is this cool or what?).

On your dual-boot question I suppose that the only way is to manually switch the BIOS settings each time you want to switch OS, as this is actually a design issue (win8 will not boot otherwise - congrats to micro$oft for "improving" the desktop experience once again). Now as far as the win8 partitions are concerned, I am pleased to report that they are visible through Nautilus like any other normal partition. Just mount and explore/explode.

On a broader note, most of the hardware seems to be working properly. Bluetooth works fine, LAN is functioning properly, Function keys to increase - decrease volume and play/pause prev/next song work fine, wifi on/off doesn't work, brightness control not working. Also I'm having some trouble with the sound. Webcam works fine.

Having said that, most of these issues should be resolved with a full install and update of h/w drivers. I just ordered a Kingston SSD to replace the internal hdd and I'm itching to do the complete install :-)

Hope this was helpful. My apologies for the lengthy post.

Note: In order to run the BIOS setup you need to boot to win8, then hold "shift" key while selecting "Shutdown" to force a complete shutdown. Then switch on the computer and press "F2" to enter BIOS setup utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new video you may need to add this to your grub boot line. This lets the live cd boot in the basic video settings.

```
xdriver=vesa nomodeset
```